# Is it possible to try my app in Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-auto

Has anyone tried to convert your app to an Android Auto?
Is it even possible to try my app in a car panel?
I wonder if it's worth trying to try or if it's not possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `KingInstaller`.
Choose path to your app's `apk` and click install.